# Flutter Doctor CocoaPods not installed

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoapods

When I run Flutter doctor:
[image]

I have tried to run sudo gem install cocoapods to install it but still the same issue.

Please not that I am running xcode 12 with the newest flutter version in the dev channel.

Any ideas?

Error after running the flutter build:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

What worked for me was to uninstall Cocoapods using `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods` and using Homebrew instead `brew install cocoapods`. P.s. I'm using an M1 Macbook.

Comment: I had to run the command:

brew link --overwrite cocoapods

after running the installation through brew

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and after hours of looking for a solution, I solved it with these steps:
(prerequisites: install homebrew first. To check if installed, in your terminal, type $ brew -v )

1. $ sudo gem uninstall cocoapods  (skip this part if cocoapods is not installed. command $pod --version , will tell you if it's installed or not)
2. $ brew install cocoapods
3. If there's an error 'The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
   The formula built,........, command $ brew link --overwrite cocoapods
4. $ brew reinstall cocoapods
5. $ flutter run

My operating system is macOS Big Sur.

Answer (score 1):

Under the Apple M1 model, if you do not need rvm and gem, you can execute

```
brew install cocoapods
```

to install cocoapods directly. Of course, if you have Homebrew, if not, please install Homebrew first.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an error when you tried to `sudo gem install cocoapods`?  I had to do `sudo gem install ruby` first to make it work on my Mac.

Comment: Thanks.  The error that I am getting after trying to run my flutter app is that CocoaPods is not installed.  Please note that I have tried running both sudo gem install cocoapods and sudo gem install ruby.

Comment: Please see the newly added picture above.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that there was no ruby installation on my mac after a clean install of MacOSX Catalina. So what I did, was first to install Ruby Version Manager with this command:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

The RVM installed Ruby on my system along with other dependencies. After that I was able to install cocoapods with the recommended command:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

and it worked flawlessly for me after that. Hope this helps. It seems that Apple has removed many developer tools lately from its systems, Ruby being one of them :(