# Flutter doctor not recognizing cocoapods even when it is installed

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoapods

I have a M1 Mac. I had this app working perfectly fine until last week. Past two days I am trying to figure out a solution for the below issue -
[image]

This is what Flutter Doctor says -
[image]

This is what gem list says -

[image]

This is what I have tried so far -

1. sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

2.sudo gem install cocoapods

Ran the app, I get the same error.

Then I uninstalled cocoapods and installed with brew -

1.sudo gem uninstalled cocoapods

2.brew install cocoapods

3.pod setup

Ran the app, I get the same error. I have cocoapods installed, why does it say not installed when running the app and using when running flutter doctor?

I have tried a lot of steps mentioned in stackoverflow and github.

Comment: Are you using an ide to run flutter commands? I mean, Android Studio or Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes I am using android studio

Comment: I got the same issue when I updated Android Studio to android-studio-2021.1.1.20-mac_arm version. Have you tried the intel version (with rosseta)?

Comment: I might have but can't be sure. I have been trying all kinds of commands to get this thing to work. Would you be able to provide me with the steps on how to do it?

Comment: @Sumchans Once you need to run your code with visual studio after its working perfect in Android Studio. This is android studio issue When you get you need to perform this step it will work.

Comment: @RaviLimbani tried it with vs code as well, it doesn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62593939/cocoapods-not-installed-or-not-in-valid-state?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-core
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Then close and open the terminal before running `flutter doctor`

Comment: Flutter doctor still says Cocoapods not installed.

Comment: Use `sudo gem list` and uninstall every cocoapods variety, and then try installing it again `sudo gem install cocoapods`.

Comment: I tried the same as well, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this not using gem install, but by switching to brew install. You may try it if you are using MacOS. Learned from the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71398813/16279954